# Scale specific workers using workless gem in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

I am using workless gem to scale delayed job related queue workers. In this process, I have to scale two different type of workers using workless. My Procfile is as follows.

```
worker: QUEUE=monthly_reports rake jobs:work
worker2: QUEUES=Dashboard_Reports,pulling rake jobs:work
```

Workless automatically scales the first worker but not my worker2. Can anyone suggest how to scale both workers using workless

Comment: heroku config:add WORKLESS_MAX_WORKERS=10 try reversing both and check

Comment: I used this option but it will scale only maximum workers up to 10 only but not dyno specific worker. I mean, my need is not to increase the dynos,but to run dynos per worker basis

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible with the way the workless gem is currently written. If you take a look at the [code](https://github.com/lostboy/workless/blob/master/lib/workless/scalers/heroku_cedar.rb) you'll see that the scaling code has the process type of 'worker' hard coded. You could modify it to support a different process type via an environment variable but it still wouldn't work with multiple process types.

Comment: Can you provide any alternative ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of an easy alternative to autoscale multiple process types based on varying delayed job queues.Is there any reason you couldn't just run all queues the main worker?